# Find the solution of SDE $dY_t=rdt+\alpha Y_tdB_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Problem: find the explicit solution of the following SDE
$$dY_t=r dt+\alpha Y_t dB_t$$
with initial condition $Y_0=y_0$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion.

Hint: consider $Z_t=\exp(-\alpha B_t+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 t)Y_t$

---

I've tried to apply Ito's formula to the process given in hint:
$$dZ_t=f(t,Y_t)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2Z_tdt+\exp(-\alpha B_t+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2t)dY_t$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\exp(-\alpha B_t+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2 t)Y_tdt+r\exp(-\alpha B_t+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2t)dt+\exp(-\alpha B_t+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2t)\alpha Y_t dB_t$$

I get stuck on that it doesn't seem we can get a equation without $Y_t$. Usually, we would have an Ito process which we can transform to the Integral form and then we can multiply the inverse of the hint to get the solution $Y_t$.

And the process in the hint is the inverse of the stochastic exponential with argument $\alpha$, I don't know if it can be used to solve the problem.

Does anyone have some hints or indicate what I've done mistakenly so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving the SDE $dX_t=bdt+cX_t dW_t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755396/solving-the-sde-dx-t-bdtcx-t-dw-t)

Comment: @Snoop, i do think so, thank you for the link, but i also want to find the way solve this problem using the hint.

Comment: For the general case of linear SDE have a look here :  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X_t=\alpha X_tdW_t$, $X_0=1$. Then, $X_t=e^{-(\alpha^2/2)t+\alpha W_t}$. The hint then suggests to consider $Z_t=X_t^{-1}Y_t$. Note that by Ito
$$d(X_t^{-1})=-X_t^{-2}dX_t+\alpha^2X_t^{-3}X_t^2dt=\alpha^2(X_t^{-1})dt-\alpha (X_t^{-1})dW_t$$
So
$$dZ_t=(X_t^{-1})dY_t+Y_td(X_t^{-1})-\alpha^2Z_tdt=r (X_t^{-1})dt$$
Therefore $Y_t=Z_tX_t=y_0X_t+r \int_0^tX_tX_s^{-1}ds$.

Comment: thanks, i solved it and get the solution $Y_t=\exp(\alpha B_t-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2t)(y_0+\int_0^t \exp(-\alpha B_s +\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2s) ds$.

Comment: @Malik correct, got a typo in mine. You're welcome.